# DateInterval Min/Max performance issue

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, date-and-time

**Bug introduced in 12.1 and persisting through 14.0.0**

**Update**

WRI has confirmed that this is a bug. CASE:4521676

---

The performance of `Min` and `Max` on a list of `DateInterval` is `O(2^n)` where `n` is the length of the list.

```
$Version
(* 12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020) *)
```

Generate some random date intervals

```
SeedRandom[11]; intervals = 30;

dateIntervals = 
 Table[DateInterval[{DateObject[{2019, 6, 15, 16, k = RandomInteger[{0, 59}]}], 
    DateObject[{2019, 6, 15, 16, RandomInteger[{k, 59}]}]}], intervals];
```

Timing `Min` for lengths `1` to `24`. This takes ~5 min on my machine.

```
timings = Table[{n, dateIntervals // Take[#, n] & // Min // AbsoluteTiming // First}, {n, 1, 24}];
```

Fit `2^n`

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[timings, b 2^n, {b}, n]

Show[ListLogPlot[timings], LogPlot[nlm[x], {x, 1, 24}]]
```

[image]

An easy workaround

```
dateIntervals // Map[Min] // Min
```

Strange that this simple operation would have performance issues.

Is this reproducible on other platforms?
Any other workaround ideas?

I have reported this to WRI.

Comment: You can increase the performance of the workaround by replacing all the `Min` with [`MinDate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinDate.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version
```

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Result plot:
[image]

Make use of the workaround with [`AbsoluteTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTime.html) and the built-in [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) .

Hope that helps.